# HAML - how to make a logout link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this route:

```
  scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
               { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout",
                 :sign_up => "signup" },
                 :controllers => {:sessions => "mobile/sessions"}
     ...
```

So I figured this would be my link to log out:

```
  =link_to("Log Out", logout_url)
```

But that is giving the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `logout_url' for #<#<Class:0x134881e88>:0x134879a08>
```

any idea how I can get the link to point correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: please run rake routes and post the result. there you should see the name of the url helper (just without the `_url` part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out `rake routes` you will notice that you have a route that looks like `destroy_user_session`.

Also, the route will only work if it's using the delete http method.

`link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_url, :method => :delete`